# Storing least-significant bit in array?

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedimage

```
public static void decodeThis(BufferedImage im){
    int w = im.getWidth();
    int h=im.getHeight();
    int[] arr=im.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, null, 0, w);
    int[] eightBit=new int[8];
    for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        System.out.printf("%x \n",arr[i]);
        }   
    }
```

So this is my code so far. I am confused as to how to read off the least-significant bit from each pixel from arr and storing it in eightBit. I just learned about arrays and BufferedImage so this is all pretty new to me - any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are familiar with the whole concept of what lsb (least-significant bit) is since you don't ask about that..?

What you need to do is to use bitwise and. That is the & operator (note: not &&). If you do 'int i & 1' you will get one if lsb of i is one and zero if its zero. Try playing around and reading avout bitwise operators and you will get the hang of it!  Just comment if you wonder about something...

Comment: So you mean something like boolean cheese=arr[1] & 1? Where do I put the bitwise and operator?

Comment: No, since java has no implicit conversation from int to bool. But if you wanted to get lsb from arr[1] and put in eg. eightBit[1] you would do: ’eightBit[1] = arr[1] & 1‘. Then eightBit[1] will be one if lsb of arr[1] is one and zero if lsb of arr[1] is zero.